# Scrapy script getting wrong data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a scrapy script which getting some correct data and after a while it start getting wrong data like price column getting wrong price and img_url column getting half correct URL and half incorrect, As Im new to scrapy so please guide me how can I handle this issue. thanks!
here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class CurtainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'curtain'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.redbubble.com/shop']
    #start_urls = ['https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains/']
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.redbubble.com/shop/shower-curtains/', callback=self.parse, headers={
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36'
        })

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//div[@class='styles__grid--197Ps']/a")
        for product in products:
            title = product.xpath(".//div[@class='styles__box--206r9 styles__paddingRight-0--fzRHs']/div[@class='styles__textContainer--1xehi styles__disableLineHeight--3n9Fg styles__nowrap--2Vk3A']/span/text()").get()
            price = product.xpath(".//span[@class='styles__text--NLf2i styles__body--3bpp7 styles__block--3OueG']/strong/span/text()").get()
            img_url = product.xpath(".//div[@class='styles__imageDiv--1zOnW']/div[@class='styles__box--206r9']/div[@class='styles__box--206r9 styles__ratioOuter--AlSwh styles__cover--zzlOp styles__square--3vP1e styles__rounded--1lyoH']/div[@class='styles__box--206r9 styles__ratioInner--KvIFM']/img/@src").get()

            yield {
                'Title' : title,
                'Price' : price,
                'Img_Url'   :   img_url,
                'User-Agent'    : response.request.headers['User-Agent']
            }
```

Comment: It seems to work properly for me. Did you setup the project using the scrapy command line? How are you handling the output? Can you write it to a file instead of printing to console because the special characters can upset the console

Comment: @ yes Im storing data into csv

Comment: please note that not all images are urls, some are base64 encoded.

Comment: any solutions to get url of those image too that are base64 encoded?

Comment: The base64 encoding is for the images binary data itself. It has no url, that data decoded is a raw image. It is used for icons or emojis sometimes.

Comment: and did you see price column Im getting wrong price

Comment: I am using your code, got 108 prices and they seem to match. you can use explicit ordering like this url https://www.redbubble.com/shop/?iaCode=u-shower-curtain&sortOrder=recent

Comment: did you get correct price for each item?

Comment: I did not match each item, but at a random pick it seemed to be okay.